# When using Tcl as a local server, how should the application be opened at start up in the browser for a user?

Tags: tcl

When using Tcl as a local server to run an application in a browser, is there a way to make it easy for the user to open it? While building it, I've been starting the Tcl server and then opening a browser and entering the local url; but is there a nice way to do this for the user?

For example, can Tcl list the browsers on the user's machine from which the user can select one, and then open it without menus in a Tk window?

I was reading about [Entice](https://www.tcl.tk/community/tcl2006/papers/Steve_Landers/Entice.pdf) but, even it was still around and functioned, I'm not trying to control a browser from user interaction in Tk but only open it in a Tk window.

Perhaps, opening the application within a browser is preferrable, since the user can run the application or multiple instances of it in more than one tab; and if a user has set up multiple profiles in a browser, it would cause issues when attempting to programmatically open one for them. But not working in this field and having the opportunity to see what is possible, I would appreciate any guidance or persective you maybe able to provide.

Thank you.

Comment: This page might be helpful: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Invoking+browsers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the *abbreviated* (and lightly edited) version of the code on https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Invoking+browsers, assuming that the URL is a full URL and not just the path part.

```
proc launchBrowser url {
    global tcl_platform
    set suffix {}

    if {$tcl_platform(platform) eq "windows"} {
        set command [auto_execok start]
        # start is a tricky Windows shell command, it needs an extra empty arg here
        lappend command {}
    } elseif {$tcl_platform(os) eq "Darwin"} {
        set command [list open]
    } else {
        set command [list xdg-open]
        set suffix &
    }
    exec {*}$command $url {*}$suffix
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see now that my main issue is I need to study how to use the command line more. This opened the default browser based on its settings but also gave errors (when running the command from the CLI only) of `ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment. Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs` which I suppose is due to the two profiles I have set in the browser.  I'll look for more options in the CL or this might not be a good approach since there may be too many options to worry about in each user's default browser.

Comment: The errors might be there in other methods of launching, but swallowed/redirected to somewhere you don't notice. Not really Tcl's problem, but you can add a redirect if you want.